# How to go back to previous page with retain the ID's in URL Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

this is my always code in go back

```
<a href="<?=site_url($controller)?>"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Go Back</a>
<br><br>
```

My question is that how can i back to my previous page that my retain my id in my previous page like this....

This is my previous page:
scms/contracts/serial/3

This is my current page:
scms/contracts/view_pm/3/Monthly

----I want to go back to "/scms/contracts/serial/3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();">Go back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know know CodeIgniter, but you can do it the old way :

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strpos($ref, '://your-site.com') !== false) {
     echo '<a href="' . $ref . '"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Go Back</a>';
} else {
     echo '<a href="javascript:history.back(-1);"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Go Back</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller you can using this:**

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='javascript:history.back(-1);'</script>";
```

**or**

```
redirect("javascript:history.back(-1);");
```

**And with Alert message you can using this:**

```
echo "<script>alert('*Alert messages here...*');window.location.href='javascript:history.back(-1);'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to redirect to your previous page , try this it work for me

```
 redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

you need to import user_agent library too

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
```

your id is also retained.